# Many IP connections to my NAS

Tags: networking

At any moment I have almost a thousand connections from / to my network attached storage (NAS), it's from D-Link ([DNS-320](http://sharecenter.dlink.com/products/DNS-320)) from unknown outside IPs.

I have a home network, everything sitting behind a Linksys router with a DD-WRT installed on it (here I see these connections). You can see the output here: https://gist.github.com/4622671.

There probably would be many more connections, but the modem only allows so many. Unfortunately, they all use a different port (otherwise I'd just block that one). Because of all of this, my internet is very slow (connections are saturated).

What can I do? I would ideally like to block them.

Comment: None of them are.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my question at the end.

Comment: Do you have any torrent client or server in your NAS? Do you want to access your NAS from out of your local network?

Comment: If you don't require access to the NAS from outside your network, then turn off remove access - or use the built in firewall in the router (if you have one)

Comment: I don't want outside access to this NAS. I see that I *do* have P2P enabled, so I'll disable it and report back.

Comment: This worked, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.

Disabling P2P in the NAS settings dropped my IP connections from around 1k to 40.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use your NAS from outside your LAN I would suggest to configure NAT on the router so the NAS won't be visible from outside.

If your router is set to automatically open ports, then see if its has an option to avoid doing so for some IPs and then configure there the IP of the NAS.

Also check your NAT list (in the router also) and see if the NAS IP is there. If it is, you can delete those entries, so users from outside your LAN won't access the NAS.

Answer (score 0):

My NAS drive has a config screen that allows you to define which IP's are allowed to talk to it.   I would look for that and just specify my own network equipment it will disreguard all other IP addresses.  Make sure the firewall on the router is working too.   Make sure there are no inbound exceptions set for the NAS.   You should be able to shut off external traffic completely without having to disable any features on the NAS.